# Can brew find / manage packages installed by manually binary download + install?

Tags: macos, install, homebrew

I  manually downloaded quite some software on my Mac, and now I want to use brew to manage all my packages.

But I don't seem to be able to find the manually installed software, maybe I missed some steps? How can I let brew manage them?

Comment: in theory yes, in practice - you probably have 500,000 files or more to look through to determine what you did. What's the actual question other than the hypothetical "yes" and "no" answers to your "I guess..." summary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you downloaded manually was with brew, just do `brew list`, you can see what you've installed using brew. Then just do `brew uninstall packageNameHere` to get rid of what you don't want.

Answer (score -1):

@Barry's answer is not responsive to the question. The command `brew list` will list all brew packages including dependencies. The original question asks about packages installed upon request.

That can be answered by, for instance,

```bash
brew leaves --installed-on-request
```

or other means as well. See this [github thread](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/10754) for more.

Comment: The question asks to "find the manually installed software" (without brew), so how does running a brew command solve this?